# loop through values in richPipe : scalding

Tags: scala, cascading, scalding

I am trying to solve a issue where I have to loop through all values in pipe.To simulate my problem I am explain through a sample problem

```
    Input file :
    number
    1
    2
    3
    4


    Output should be
    number sumOfSmaller 
    1        0            
    2        1             
    3        3
    4        6
```

So for each value I have to read all of the records in pipe and apply function sumOfSmaller.
I have no idea on how to loop through values in scalding pipe.
Using map I can apply function of each element of list but I want to avoid  this approch

Answer (score 1):

You can get the contents of the whole pipe with 
`val wholePipe = pipe.groupAll.toList`, and then join it with itself, and apply your function: `pipe.groupAll.join(wholePipe).values.map { case (x, list) => sumOfSmaller(x, list) }`

This is not a very good idea though, especially, if your pipe is of any decent size. Knowing more details about what it is you are really trying to do should almost certainly allow for a better approach.